# MySQL - Selecting closest row to a certain time on each day of a month

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table with two columns

TimeStamp of type TIMESTAMP

A of type FLOAT

This table is created and updated by an external application, so inserts and updates are outside of my control.  The table design can't be altered in any way.

What I need to do is select each entry closest to and before 10AM for each day during the entire past month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post more detail about how your current query is failing. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, I'm just really lost on where to start to do this in query.  My SQL knowledge is very basic and I can easily get the information for a single day, but unsure of how to go about getting a result of one entry per day closest to 10AM.  This is basically to make up for a shortcoming within the software and creating an extra report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner pre-query should get on a per year/month basis, prior to the month you are currently in.  This is forced by a SQLVariable created by the formatted 'YYYY-MM-01' date, such as today... 2012-03-19, keep just year/month but force 01.  This also implies timestamp of 12:00:00 am (midnight).  The NEXT @ variable is to determine the first of the month PRIOR to the one just computed... thus 2012-02-01.  That builds the variables for the WHERE clause queried against your table of timestamp/float values.

Now, you can get the maximum time, grouped by just the common date portion of the timestamp, but retaining the full actual date AND time of the entry where the HOUR() of the entry is before 10am...

From that, re-join back to the original table where the FINAL "LastPerDay" time matches the per-day basis.  Now, you MAY get multiple entries if the actual last timestamp entry for the same day actually HAS multiple exact time entries to the granularity of hh:mm:ss (or whatever precision)

```
select
      PreQuery.JustTheDate,
      YT2.FloatColumnName
   from
      ( select
              Date_Format( YT.TimeStampColumn, '%Y-%m-%d' ) JustTheDate,
              max( YT.TimeStampColumn ) as LastPerDay
           from
              ( select @FirstOfThisMonth := Date_Format( '%Y-%m-01' ),
                       @FirstOfPriorMonth := Date_Sub( @FirstOfThisMonth, interval 1 month ) ) sqlvars,
              YourTable YT
           where
                  YT.TimeStampColumn >= @FirstOfPriorMonth
              AND YT.TimeStampColumn < @FirstOfThisMonth
              AND Hour( YT.TimeStampColumn ) < 10
           group by
              `JustTheDate`
           order by
              `JustTheDate` DESC ) PreQuery

      JOIN YourTable YT2
         ON PreQuery.LastPerDay = YT2.TimeStampColumn
```

Comment: That got me on the right track.  Thank you very much.  For whatever reason I just wasn't getting my head wrapped around the problem right.